# How do I insert an HTML form into a MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am working on a billing system,, It's very basic right now but I was wondering if you could help me with my code. How do I insert the data from the HTML form into a MySQL database? My code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('connect-mysql.php');

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $charge = $_POST['charge'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $client_no = $_POST['client_no'];
    $client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
    $check_no = $_POST['check_no'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    $cash = $_POST['cash'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $staff_initials = $_POST['staff_initials'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', 'payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
        die('There was an error when trying to process your payment. Please contact technical support.');
    } //end of nested if statement

} // end of the main if statement
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>New Payment</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please Input Payment Details</h1>
<form action="new_payment.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Payment</legend>
    <label>Date:<input type="text" name="date" /></label><br>
    <label>Today's Charge: <input type="text" name="charge" /></label><br>
    <label>Today's Payment: <input type="text" name="payment" /></label><br>
    <label>Client Number: <input type="text" name="client_no" /></label><br>
    <label>Client Name: <input type="text" name="client_name" /></label><br>
    <label>Check Number: <input type="text" name="check_no" /></label><br>
    <label>Check: <input type="text" name="check" /></label><br>
    <label>Cash: <input type="text" name="cash" /></label><br>
    <label>Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" /></label><br>
    <label>Staff Initials: <input type="text" name="staff_initials" /></label><br>
</fieldset>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Process Payment">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, this is very important that I finish this in a timely manner...

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  It might not work but, you haven't really explained the problem clearly.

Comment: It is critical that you used prepared queries to isolate the data from your query.  As it stands now, you are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.

Comment: are you going to use MySQL or MySQLi ?

Comment: I just want to reiterate Brad's comment. This is completely vulnerable to SQL injection. For example what if I change the staff initials field to read "JW'); DROP TABLE payments; --" Check out more information about SQL injection here http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

First Error:-

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))

<input type="submit" value="Process Payment">
```

change to this:-

```
if($_POST['process'] == 'Process Payment') 
<input name="process" type="submit" id="process" value="Process Payment">
```

You can use this one instead (to prevent SQL injection):

```
// CONNECTION TO DATABASE

$mysqli = new mysqli('HOST','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DATABASE'); 

// CHECK CONNECTION

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}        

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlinsert);

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $charge = $_POST['charge'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $client_no = $_POST['client_no'];
    $client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
    $check_no = $_POST['check_no'];
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    $cash = $_POST['cash'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $staff_initials = $_POST['staff_initials'];

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss",$date, $charge, $payment, $client_no, $client_name, $check_no, $check, $cash, $notes, $staff_initials );

//EXECUTE QUERY
$stmt->execute();

$rowcount = $stmt->affected_rows;


if ($rowcount > 0)
{
echo "Success!";
}

else
{
echo "Error!";
}

//CLOSE EXECUTE
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Missing the initialisation of the `$mysqli` variable. `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");`

Comment: If your problem solved with the solutions given, please tick the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you should change

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="Process Payment">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Process Payment">
```

and put $ for payment in INSERT command

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `name="submit"`, in case you might later try to use jQuery -- there's a conflict with a jQuery method.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having problem in inserting to database you should change

```
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', 'payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";
```

to

```
 $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";
```

You forgot to put $ before payment in Insert Value

Comment: While this may directly answer the question, it isn't a correct answer as it doesn't address the extreme vulnerability to SQL injections in the rest of the code.