# How to insert data from an HTML form into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

Please tell me what's wrong with my code!!!!

new-payment.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Process New Payment</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Please Input Payment Details</h1>
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Payment</legend>
    <form action="process-payment.php" method="post" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>Date:</td><td><input type="date" name="date" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Today's Charge:</td><td><input type="text" name="charge" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Today's Payment:</td><td><input type="text" name="payment" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Client Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="client_no" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Client Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="client_name" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Check Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="check_no" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Check Amount:</td><td><input type="text" name="check" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cash Amount:</td><td><input type="text" name="cash" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Notes:</td><td><input type="text" name="notes" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Staff Initials:</td><td><input type="text" name="staff_initials" /><br /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Process Payment">
    </form>
</fieldset>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

process-payment.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'DBNAME');
define('DB_USER', 'USERNAME');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if (!$link) {
    dir('There was a problem when trying to connect to the host. Please contact Tech Support. Error: ' . mysql_error());    
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$link) {
    dir('There was a problem when trying to connect to the database. Please contact Tech Support. Error: ' . mysql_error());    
}

$date = $_POST['date'];
$charge = $_POST['charge'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$client_no = $_POST['client_no'];
$client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
$check_no = $_POST['check_no'];
$check = $_POST['check'];
$cash = $_POST['cash'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$staff_initials = $_POST['staff_initials'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

?>
```

I do not know what is wrong but I get an error when I press Process Payment:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check, cash, notes, staff_initials) >VALUES ('2012-09-24', '$0.00', '$20.00', '46' at line 1

Comment: if '$20.00' is set to an integer in the database, it wont work.  Lets see your database.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575444/how-do-i-insert-an-html-form-into-a-mysql-database/12575726

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert an HTML form into a MySQL Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575444/how-do-i-insert-an-html-form-into-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2):

`CHECK` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  You must enclose it in backticks to use it as a column or table identifier.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, `check`, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";
```

Note that your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` over each of those input variables.

```
// As in:
$charge = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['charge']);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('".$date."', '".$charge."', '".$payment."', '".$client_no."', '".$client_name."', '".$check_no."', '".$check."', '".$cash."', '".$notes."', '".$staff_initials."')";
```

And it may pay to look up MySQL PDO instead of using the depreciated connection code you are using.

Comment: No need. The double-quoted outer string will correctly interpolate the variables inside the inner quotes as long as the variables are escaped.

Comment: look at this answer for PDO implementation http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/is-there-any-sql-injection-for-this-php-login-example/34668#34668

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo all element and see wheather some variable may be blank or empty or not.

I have same error. I solved by this way